# ssas tabular 2016 Many to many relationship

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBLGS.png)i'm new here ,and in the ssas tabular modeling, im working on a project and i have to do a many to many relationship in ssas tabular 2016 BUT they give me this probleme.

my model is like this where index is note a primary key in both tables and i want to join the two tables with it.

thank you all !
model[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMU1h.png)

Comment: did you set the relationship direction to Bi-Directional? SSAS 2016 supports many-2-many, if that is set up

Comment: hello jon thanks for your help, but no, i  dont mean the bidirectional filter, i mean its a many to many i've a lot of student in a lot in classes and a lot of classes with a lot of student did you get it?( 1,*) --------  (1,* ) RELATION,which is not supported

Answer (score 1):

SSAS 2016 & 2017 does not support the Many-To-Many Relationship nativity in SSAS, you will have to use a bridge table. One other option which may meet your requirements is to activate the Bi-Directional filter in a Many-To-One relationship. A good outline is blogged about [here](https://blog.tallan.com/2017/02/09/analysis-services-tabular-many-to-many-relationships-bridge-tables-and-blank-members/).

Only SSAS 2019/Azure Analysis Services (Compatibility level 1500) & Power BI allows the native selection of Many-To-Many relationships.

Comment: can you please help ,e create this bridge table?